# Can I use ELMAH along with OWIN?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, owin, elmah

I have a project built on `ASP.NET Web API` and `OWIN`. It is needed to use `ELMAH` in this project.

Simply adding `ELMAH` nuget does not work. URL `/elmah.axd` can not be handled correctly by the `OWIN`. Probably due to not having a suitable middleware for it.

I read somewhere that there is an experimental code for it. But was not able to find it. Anyone knows a solution, nuget package, code snippet, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ELMAH isn't officially supported in OWIN. Atif Aziz (developer of ELMAH) made an experimental port here: https://bitbucket.org/raboof/elmah-owin/src/default/. The code isn't maintained though and probably won't evolve, since OWIN middleware is now part of ASP.NET Core.